# Redis don't start

Tags: redis

I have redis server 3.0.6 and ubuntu 16.04.
my config file

```
tcp-keepalive 60
#bind 127.0.0.1
requirepass qwerty
maxmemory-policy noeviction
appendonly yes
appendfilename redis-test.aof
```

and redis server don't run

> Can't open the append-only file: Read-only file system

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: The file system on which `redis-test.aof` resides is mounted as read-only. The whole purpose of this file is to write changes to disk. So the disk must be writable.

Check if you used the `ro` option while mounting the drive. Run

```
$ mount
```

to list all the mountpoints. Check the one on which you want your aof file to reside.

To remount the disk as read-write, use the following command:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

If that doesn't help, see the system logs if there are any file system errors. To correct these, you will need to run `fsck`.

Comment: if you need install redis-server an ubuntu, use this page https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: There is no mentioning of your problem. I personally would prefer installtion from the package manager and not compile from source.